# magento 2 get configruble attribute

Tags: magento2, attributes, configurable-product

how I can get all attributes that used for creating a configurable product?
did we have API for this?
 and how we can create configurable attribute by admin panel

Comment: i need API ... I wanna create a product on mobile and for creating configurable product I need to get all attribute that used for creating config

Answer (score 0):

```
$product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributes($product);
```

You might want to add some checks, in case the product you are supplying isn't configurable.

`\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::getConfigurableAttributes` is only available there.

Comment: so how we can tell Magento an attribute can use as configure for configurable product